# Linux group and user management

Tags: c++, c, linux

A need to implement a functionality for adding/removing users and groups on Linux system.
I use these POSIX calls:

- void setgrent(void) - for opening group file
- struct group *getgrent(void); - for reading group structure
- void endgrent(void) - for closing file

The idea is to read all user and group structures in a vector, modify them, and then rewrite existing /etc/passwd and /etc/group files. Getgrent() function description tells that these functions do have static variables with allocated memory and that pointer should not be freed manually. That means that endgrent() should free all pointers on heap. This raises a problem, because structure group holds a lot of data on heap. So if I decide to store it somewhere I need to do a strdup() for every member in gr_mem as well as for other members, so I don't lose any data.

Is there a way to store group structures more efficiently? Maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

```
struct group
{
   char *gr_name; // The name of the group. 
   gid_t gr_gid; // The group ID of the group. 
   char **gr_mem; // array of group members
}
```

Comment: No, but why doing several `strdup` bother you? You won't have that much users (systems with many thousands of users are rare, and this fits easily on all desktop machines....)

Comment: All of those calls are POSIX.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Actually I'm developing an embedded system. That is why I'm trying to minimize read/write operations and also gain maximal performance. I'm ok with this solution, just hoping for any community criticisms.

Comment: @Duck, my mistake. Only fgetgrent() and other modifications are non Posix functions.

Comment: @JimGarrison, didn't know about such project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are reentrant versions of those functions . See **man getgrent_r** for example:

```
int getgrent_r(struct group *gbuf, char *buf,size_t buflen, struct group **gbufp);
```

This version takes a pointer to a memory location that you have to provide.

You can then free() that structure whenever it is convenient, without making unnecessary copies.